# Click button containing some text

Tags: javascript

I want to create a "script" to click in a button everytime it contains 'PLACE BET'

i could do that easy with classes, but the problem is the button have the same classes, only thing different is the text.

````
<button type="button" name="button" style="z-index:10;" class="place_bet crash-button-bet bet_placed">PLACE BET</button>```

when i click:

```<button type="button" name="button" style="z-index:10;" class="place_bet crash-button-bet bet_placed">BETTING (44) (click to cancel)</button>```
````

Answer (score 2):

if i understood you right you wanna add a event listener which change the inner HTML of The button.

If so:

````
<script>
function changeButton(){
 if (document.getElementById('btnplacebet').textContent == "PLACE BET") 
   {
       document.getElementById('btnplacebet').textContent = "BETTING (44) (click to cancel)";
   }
   else 
   {
     document.getElementById('btnplacebet').textContent = "PLACE BET";
   }
}
</script>

<button onclick="changeButton()" id="btnplacebet" type="button" name="button" style="z-index:10;" class="place_bet crash-button-bet bet_placed">PLACE BET</button>```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function changeButtonText(){
 if (document.getElementById('btn-id').textContent == "PLACE BET") 
   {
       document.getElementById('btn-id').textContent = "CLICK TO CANCEL";
   }
   else 
   {
     document.getElementById('btn-id').textContent = "PLACE BET";
   }
}
</script>

<button onclick="changeButtonText()" id="btn-id" type="button">PLACE BET</button>
```